# last-modified vs expires precedence

Tags: http, web, httprequest, httpresponse

I have read through lot of discussions, and found most of the claim saying `expires` is higher precedence over `last-modified`, meaning if a `response` already expired, it will not even send out `if-modified-since` to server and of course the `response` code will not be 304.

But my situation is totally weird, I have returned back `last-modified` in `response`, and somehow CDN/proxy side add in `expires` header, which value is same as `date` `response` header, I suppose same value in `expires` and `date` header will cause the `response` stale immediately, but in fact, my client browser will still send out request with `if-modified-since` header, this will cause a 304 `response` code returned from the server.

I read throught `RFC 2616`, it doesn't tell much as well. So what happen to this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost 2 years but find no answer...

I managed find out some [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching):

> The freshness lifetime is calculated based on several headers. If a
>   "Cache-control: max-age=N" header is specified, then the freshness
>   lifetime is equal to N. If this header is not present, which is very
>   often the case, it is checked if an Expires header is present. If an
>   Expires header exists, then its value minus the value of the Date
>   header determines the freshness lifetime. Finally, if neither header
>   is present, look for a Last-Modified header. If this header is
>   present, then the cache's freshness lifetime is equal to the value of
>   the Date header minus the value of the Last-modified header divided by
>   10.

Although I can't find confirmed precedence in RFC, but I think this MDN quote is quite reliable enough.

It is pretty normal if some browser doesn't implement in this way... So to avoid any issue, the best is to not return these two headers in the response at the same time.